# Not saving graph to specified folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am generating the graph and saving to the specified folder but no figure is saved in that specific destination. The graph is generated for one time only and I am getting an error after that. Here is my code

```
 import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

final_obj=np.array([[  8.31907313 ,  0.17300669],
 [  8.50432396 ,  0.19566612],
 [  8.50432396 ,  0.19566612],
 [  8.50432396  , 0.19566612],
 [  8.50432396   ,0.19566612],
 [  8.50432396  , 0.19566612],
 [  8.50432396  , 0.19566612],
 [  8.50432396  , 0.19566612],
 [  8.50432396  , 0.19566612],
 [  8.50432396  , 0.19566612],
 [  8.50432396   ,0.19566612],
 [  8.50432396   ,0.19566612],
 [  8.50432396   ,0.19566612]])

print(final_obj)
x1=[]
y1=[]
for z in range(0,5):
     for i in range(0,len(final_obj)):
          X=final_obj[i][0]
          x1.append(X)
          Y=final_obj[i][1]
          y1.append(Y)


     plt.plot(x1, y1, label = "line 1",marker='o',linestyle = 'None')
     plt.xlabel("X-axis")
     plt.ylabel("Y-axis")
     plt.legend()
     plt.show()
     save_results_to = "C:\\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\SRMMEA\venv\IRIS_GRAPH"
     plt.savefig(save_results_to+'GRAPH_{}.png'.format(z), format="PNG")
```

And it showing an error for the above code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\silvspbm.py", line 35, in <module>
    plt.savefig(save_results_to+'GRAPH_{}.png'.format(z), format="PNG")
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 710, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 2035, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2263, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 526, in print_png
    with cbook.open_file_cm(filename_or_obj, "wb") as fh:
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 624, in open_file_cm
    fh, opened = to_filehandle(path_or_file, mode, True, encoding)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 609, in to_filehandle
    fh = io.open(fname, flag, encoding=encoding)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\PycharmProjects\\SRMMEA\x0benv\\IRIS_GRAPHGRAPH_0.png'
```

Comment: Your traceback doesn't match your code. In one case you're using string concatenation, the other you're using `format()`

Comment: @roganjosh an edit has been made you can check that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
save_results_to = "C:\\Users\hp\PycharmProjects\SRMMEA\venv\IRIS_GRAPH"
```

Replace the above code with this code to get the desired result

```
save_results_to = "C:\\Users\\hp\\PycharmProjects\\SRMMEA\\venv\\IRIS_GRAPH\\"
```

Comment: Worked for me! before, the filepath of plt.savefig() was listed via os.chdir() so it looked like plt.savefir("folder/pic{0}.png".format(i)) and it always threw and error when exporting around the 10th picture. Thanks!